# SQL 2008 setting compatibility level

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

When I try to add a data-base in SQL Server 2008 (Right clicking on Databases folder->New Database) the only compatibility options given to me in the options tab are 70, 80, and 90.

However, I require the use of the DATE object, which doesn't work unless I set the compatibility level to 100.

I've tried using 
exec sp_dbcmptlevel mydb, 100;
GO

However, I get the following error:
Valid values of the database compatibility level are 60, 65, 70, 80, or 90.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it certainly appears that the database is a SQL Server 2005 database, not SQL Server 2008.  Does it have a "100.something" next to the server name?  If not, it's not SQL Server 2008.

Are you using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, or an earlier version?

Comment: I think you're onto something here.
I just checked my version with select @@version and it returns
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3042.00 (Intel X86)   Feb  9 2007 22:47:07   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7600: ) 

However I am using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio (even double checked via help-about dialogue).

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio can connect to older server versions, but the version of the server is the important part, in terms of whether it supports the `date` date type, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Leave it blank.  Compatibility level is there to allow you to set the compatibility to a lower version of the database (if you need to).

Comment: Are you saying that it defaults to 100?
Also, what do you mean 'leave it blank'? the drop-down menu in the options tab does not have a blank option just 70,80,90.

Comment: The options menu starts out blank (if not, then it might be a 2005 server)

Comment: Make sure you're connecting to a 2008 version of the database server (whether or not you're using SSMS 2005 or 2008)

Comment: I hate to sound like a terrible noob here but I have looked but cannot find where I can pick the specific version of the db server I want to connect to.

Comment: That's not a choice you have.  It depends on what is installed.  What does it say next to the server name in the Object Explorer window?  (something like servername (SQL Server 9.0.4035 - loginname)

Comment: @bdukes: You're right, its blank for me because I'm using SSMS 2005 - in 2008, it should have an option for 2008 (100)

Comment: My server name had SQLEXPRESS attached to it...getting rid of that when i connect defaulted my version to 10.

Thanks to the both of you, you've been fantastic help.

Comment: That means you have 2 versions installed.  2008 and 2005 express.

Comment: Yeah the funny thing is I don't know where the 2005 express even came from. I suspect it may have been installed during the visual studio install and I didn't catch it.

Comment: Yeah. Its installed with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Have you by chance tried the following?

```
ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in SQL Server Management Studio: right click on database -> properties -> options, and choose compatibility level